# .NET huge Issues

Tags: .net

.NET on my web server is completely messed up.
IIS would not start saying it could not load .net 2.0.
I tried to repair .net 3.5 and it would error out. So I removed 3.5 and tried to reinstall it, again it errored out. I tried to repair 2.0 and got the same issues. Again then tried to uninstall 2.0 and the uninstall errored out.
I used the .net clean up utility to remove everything .net. 
That completed successfully. now I am trying to install .net 2.0 service pack one and it too is erroring out saying

```
 Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0a: [2] Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft   
.NET Framework 2.0a. MSI returned error code 1603
```

We are completely dead. Please any help possible would be great

Comment: Anything in your event log?

Comment: What windows version? Some versions are baked into the OS, and they need to be enabled/installed/updated through Windows Control Panels.

Comment: The OS is server 2003

Answer (score 1):

Look to see if you have any dead / hung msiexec processes, maybe MSI has crapped out on you and not gone away.

Have a look at [**this blog post**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160228174600/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2005/08/01/446328.aspx) as well to help narrow down that could be causing the 1603 failure.